# How to use a variationnal autoencoder for time series?

Tags: deep-learning, gaussian, autoencoder, normalize, data-transform

I am using an example of Variationnal AutoEncoder on MNIST data (2D images) made by others (http://louistiao.me/posts/implementing-variational-autoencoders-in-keras-beyond-the-quickstart-tutorial/) and change it to use it on music but I have a problem.

I choosed this example because the author don't use convolutionnal layers, only Dense layers so it is easy to use it for time series.

Images values are in the interval [0,1] ( [0,255]/255 ).

Musical values are in the interval [-1,1].

So I changed the musical values to fit the model: `x = (x+1)/ 2`  -> [0,1].

Result: the network isn't learning (my val_loss doesn't decrease).

I have no idea why !!!

PS: I tried to changed the activation relu/sigmoid to tanh instead of changing the data. The loss was decreasing but she was negative... and I had no good results either.

Comment: Can't you transform our data before input to the model? Sum 1 and divide by 2, this will make your input be [0,1].

Comment: This is what I tried but it doesn't work. I think we lose something in this transformation because the 0 is know at 0.5 and it may perturbate the gradrient descent ? (I'm trying to guess why it doesn't work).

Comment: You lose the distribution of the data, but you can use the inverse operation to reconstruct the data, can't you?

Comment: What is exact the problem you are getting? It's also hard to help you without seeing the architecture of your network.

Comment: The problem take place even before reversing data.
This is the code that was working for 2D image (here is the link: http://louistiao.me/posts/implementing-variational-autoencoders-in-keras-beyond-the-quickstart-tutorial/).
I used this one because the author used 784 inputs flatten and not a convolutionnal entry so it is more easy to pass to time series.
I changed my data to be beetween 0 and 1 but the network isn't learning.
Apart that, I do exactly the same.